# save user's images in a folder on file system Spring MVC

Tags: spring, file, spring-mvc

I  have an application where users can enter some informations and image, So first I saved images in database but I read that it's not a good practice and it's cost when deploy the application. So I want to save images on filesystem , I read that we should not save them in  the application , So I want to save them in an external folder in the file system. I choose them in a folder E:/images, it's worked fine . My question is what I can do in a production application to save images (there will not be E:/images) , How can I create a folder on the server where I deploy the application and how can I mention it in the controller instead of (E:/images). I m using Spring MVC. 
Here my Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add ( @RequestParam("prix") Long prix, 
            RequestParam("adresse") String ville,
            @RequestParam("categorie") String categorie,
            @RequestParam("photos") MultipartFile file,
            ) throws FileNotFoundException


 {

   String chemin=null;
   if (!file.isEmpty())
     {
      try {
       String orgName = file.getOriginalFilename();
       // this line to retreive just file name 
       String 
       name=orgName.substring(orgName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1,orgName.length());
       chemin="e:\\images\\"+name;
       File file1=new File(chemin);
       file.transferTo(file1);
         } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  }

    }
    annonce.setImage(chemin);
    annonce.setTitre(prix);
    annonce.setCorps(ville);
    annonce.setPrix(cetegorie)
    annoncedao.save(annonce);
    return "SuccessAddAnnonce";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add somename.property file in your classpath. Add below line in it:

```
imagepath=e:\\images;
```

Now you make a bean for property file in your spring configuration file as below.

```
<bean id="projectProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:somename.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

now in your controller, add the bean:

```
@Resource(name="projectProperties")
  private Properties projectProperties;
```

now change your line:

```
chemin=projectPropertiesProperties.getProperty("imagepath")+name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for hard coded file path in code. Use property file and give it to production team. So whenever you deploy your application on production, in property file just change the file path where you want to save your files.

Comment: Actually It is my personal application. Do you have an example how to do that ?

Comment: Check my new answer